# VBA Code to allow only paste special in the excel template

Tags: excel, vba

HI,

I am using an Excel template with columns having different formulas and format, I don't want those formats to be replaced when i paste something from another excel sheet.

Can anybody provide me, just a VBA code which i will paste in the VBA  editor and all the paste operation in my excel template will be PASTE SPECIAL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use Events in your workbook. Sorry if my translations are not in line with yours Excel, but I have Polish version of MS Office. However, if you press CTRL+F11 and open VB Editor in the Project Pane you should have something like "Microsoft Excel Objects" and there objects corresponding to Spreadsheets and Workbook. Now, in **ThisWorkbook** place a code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub WorkBook_Open()
    MsgBox "this happens when workbook is opened"
    Application.OnKey "^v","my_function"
End Sub
```

This code will override the CTRL+V and run my_function() when this key combination is pressed. Given the function above you may now insert new module and add there a sub e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Sub my_function()
    MsgBox "you have pressed ctrl+v"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteForumlas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

For more information about the events see e.g. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

If the code above does not work check the value of Application.EnableEvents, and if neccessary change it's value in immediate window.

Moreover, in **Sheet1** you may try to do something with change event. Using this event you may prevent excel from changing the styles, although the first solution should be esier to implement. Below is the code for the change event.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     MsgBox "the value was changed"
End Sub
```

Hope it helped.

Some links on events in Excel

- http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm
- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;213220&Product=xlw

Comment: actually i had this code,was looking fr another way..but thanx a lot anyways !! accepted answer

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, but why were you looking for another way?

Comment: When we use VBA macros in Workbook,it always asks user if they want to enable or disable macros ? my clients are insisting on not to use macros because of the security problems..but finally figured out another way which adds VBA code on the runtime and removes the code dynamically..this helps me in bypassing the Enable macros pop up and client would be happy... :-)